# How to get complex Oracle UserDefinedType as output of stored proc in SQLALCHEMY

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have 2 user defined DataTypes in Oracle which i use in output of a stored proc. How can i call this proc using SQLALCHEMY and print output? I tried creating a types.UserDefinedType subclass and bind result param with it but i keep getting error which says that this type is not supported by cx_oracle

```
Create or replace TYPE type1 as Object (
      param1 NUMBER(15,0),
      param2 clob);
/
create or replace TYPE t_type1 as TABLE OF type1;
/
create or replace PROCEDURE "DO_SOMETHING" (
      results OUT t_type1,
      status OUT CHAR,
      status_msg OUT VARCHAR2)
```

Below is code i am trying to use to call above Stored proc. How do i bind a pram if stored proc which is of user defined data type in oracle?

```
connection = engine.connect()
try:
    proc_query = text(
        "begin DO_SOMETHING(:results,:status, :status_msg); end;",
        bindparams=[outparam('results', <WHAT TO PUT HERE>, outparam('status', CHAR),
                    outparam('status_msg', VARCHAR)])
    result = connection.execute(proc_query)
    status_code = result.out_parameters['results'].strip()
    err_nbr = result.out_parameters['status']
    err_msg = result.out_parameters['status_msg'].strip()
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
    print("Error occured in refresh_view" ,e)
    raise e
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I tweaked a little to use VARCHAR2 instead of CLOB to make life easier :)
But this should help - 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE1 AS OBJECT (
      PARAM1 NUMBER(15,0),
      PARAM2 VARCHAR2(1024));
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_TYPE1 AS TABLE OF TYPE1;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DO_SOMETHING (
      RESULTS OUT T_TYPE1,
      STATUS OUT CHAR,
      STATUS_MSG OUT VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    STATUS_MSG :='STATUS_MSG';
    STATUS := '1';
    RESULTS := T_TYPE1(TYPE1(13,'MESSAGE'));
END;
/
```

> Call -

```
SET SERVEROUT ON;
DECLARE
    RESULTS T_TYPE1;
    STATUS CHAR;
    MSG VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
    DO_SOMETHING(RESULTS, STATUS, MSG);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(STATUS||','|| MSG);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RESULTS(1).PARAM1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RESULTS(1).PARAM2);
END;
/
```

> Output -

```
1,STATUS_MSG
13
MESSAGE
```

Comment: Hi Shrek, Thanks for response but i am looking for a way to execute this proc using SQLALCHEMY. I am able to execute the proc they way you mentioned but through SQLALCHEMY i am only able to execute those procs successfully where no user defined types are used as IN or OUT params. I will edit my question to add more info.